# New windows in session fallback

Tags: window, gnome-classic

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit). I hate unity, so I use gnome-session-fallback. Everything works fine (OK, not as well as it worked in gnome2...) but if I open a new window, it always appears in the top-left corner corner and its menu bar is behind my top menu bar (with application menu, places, etc.).

How can I fix it? It annoys me a lot. Please help!

Comment: Have you got the "place windows" plugin in CCSM ticked or not ticked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your video card supports 3D Accelleration, you might consider using the compiz window placement plugin.

Install compizconfig-settings-manager:

[compizconfig-settings-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/)

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `compiz --replace`

If you want to change the way the windows are placed on your desktop, start the compizconfig-settings-manager:

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm`

Find the "Place Windows" plugin, it will have an option called "Placement Mode", you can choose the one that you like best there.